# How can I open a new activity when the right button is selected (in a radioGroup) and you click the "next" button

Tags: android, android-activity

I have in my project 2 Activitys.

The first Activity: question
and the second Activity:newsite

(both standing in the AndroidManifest.xml)

I have 4 buttons (the first button is the right answer)

When the first button is selected and i click the button "next" than open the newsite (new Activity)

What for a code i need for my Project?

The question.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:text="Here is a question" />

    <Button

        android:text="next"
        android:background="@null"
        android:id="@+id/next"



    <RadioGroup

        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1">

        <RadioButton
            android:text="this is the right answer"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:text="answertext"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:text="answertext"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:text="answertext"
            android:id="@+id/radioButton4" />




    </RadioGroup>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to do something like this (I suggest you to put this in `onCreate` method):

```
Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
RadioButton radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);

next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (radioButton1.isChecked()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(question.this, newsite.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
});
```